# how to use google.script.run as if it was a function

Tags: google-apps-script

In a Google Apps Script, I have the following script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mypage');
}

function writeSomething() {
  return "<h1>hi people</h1>";
}
```

and the following html file:

```
<html>
  <a id="caller" href="#">update</a>
  <br>
  <div id="div">waiting...</div>
<script>
function go() {
  var a=google.script.run.writeSomething();
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=a;
}
document.getElementById('caller').onclick = go;
</script>
</html>
```

When I click on the "update" link, the div content changes from "waiting..." to "undefined". I suppose that google.script.run cannot be called as a function.
So, how can I solve this trouble? (obviously, this is a toy example; I need a way to update the div content from the script and not from the html file)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The function writeSomething() is run asynchronously so it happens but doesn't return the response as a local function would. (This is standard for JavaScript talking to a server). Instead, you need to specify a "callback" function which gets invoked when writeSomething() is finished.

Here's the corrected version of your HTML:

```
<html>
  <a id="caller" href="#">update</a>
  <br>
  <div id="div">waiting...</div>
<script>
function callback(whatToWrite) {
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=whatToWrite;
}
function go() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).writeSomething();
}
document.getElementById('caller').onclick = go;
</script>
</html>
```

Or equivalently, you can specify the callback function inline:

```
...
<script>    
function go() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(whatToWrite) {
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=whatToWrite;
  }).writeSomething();
}
...
```

Comment: So how would it work if "<h1> hi people </h1>" was actually an interactive jquery element (that you can select) and you'd want to return the index of the selection to the google apps script? Any ideas on how to do that? Or put in other words: how to return "<h1> hi people </h1>" back to the google apps script, so you can edit it further in that environment?

Comment: For some reason, I can't wrap my head around the function names used in this example, whatToWrite, WriteSomething, ... What about function arguments? how should they be dealt with in the callback?

Comment: OMG, @CoeryG! You are the first person to make this make sense in my brain and now I have a working foundation to build more dynamic tools from. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!