# Can I store an apps script return value (string) as a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've got an apps script function that returns a stored value from the built-in PropertiesService. I'm calling this function when the user clicks a button and want to store the returned value as a JS variable. I know the function is being called and works as expected, but I keep getting "undefined.mp3" back. Any ideas?

### Code.gs

```
function getMP3Name () {
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    return userProperties.getProperty('mp3name'); 
}
```

### Index.html

```
function onSuccess(mp3) {
    return(mp3)
}

var fileFullName = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getMP3Name(); + '.' + fileExtension;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use google.script.run as if it was a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487045/how-to-use-google-script-run-as-if-it-was-a-function)