# Function Call from Google.Script.Run returns 'undefined'

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to call a function from a web app I have created using **google.script.run**
the function simply helps me find the index of a value in a list. When I call the function normally it works fine, when I call it from the web app however, it always returns 'undefined'. Even when I pass it the same values? I first thought it was because the arrays were global so I try to define them in the function and still no luck. Can anyone see anything I can be missing? I tried using with the failureHandler, but the script isn't *failing* per se

I have even tried using the onSuccessHandler after finding a similar thread on here saying that's how you *return* a value from a server-called function..but still no luck

below is the function i am trying to call

```
function findStockCode(stockName){

  var stockListi  = ss.getRangeByName("stockName").getValues().filter(String);
  var stockCodesi = ss.getRangeByName("stockCodes").getValues().filter(String);

  for(i = 0; i < stockListi.length; i++){
    if(stockListi[i].toString() === stockName.toString()){
      return stockCodesi[i].toString();
    }
  }
  return "not found"
}
```

and here is how I am calling it:

```
 $("#productSelection1").change(function(){

          alert(google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessCode).findStockCode("SMK SALMON TRIM W/PEPPER"));

     $("#productCode1").html("code");
   });
```

eventually I want the **productCode1** value to change to a corresponding product code when the product name is picked in **productSelection1**

Comment: Your return from `findStockCode`, will be sent to a function called `onSuccessCode`, once the execution of the `findStockCode` function is done on the server side.show us your onSuccessCode. `Google.script.run.function()` calls your function on the script and moves to the next line (asynchronous call) their is no waiting or return from it.

Comment: To add to what Jack said, Your alert should be inside a function named `onSuccessCode`. `function onSuccessCode(code){alert(code)}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use google.script.run as if it was a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487045/how-to-use-google-script-run-as-if-it-was-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
$("#productSelection1").change(function(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(str){
      alert(str);
    })
    .findStockCode("SMK SALMON TRIM W/PEPPER"));
    $("#productCode1").html("code");
});
```